# How to plot a 3D line using plotly.graph_objects?

Tags: plot, plotly

I want to draw a line between two points in a 3D plot. But, I can not use plotly.express for some reasons as suggested in the documentation. https://plotly.com/python/3d-line-plots/

Is it possible to draw a line in a 3D plot using the plotly.graph_objects module ? If so, how ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found this solution:

**plotly.express solution:**

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np 

x = np.array([0,1])
y = np.array([1,1])
z = np.array([1,1])
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y":y, "z":z})

fig = px.line_3d(df, x="x", y="y", z="z")
fig.show()
```

output :

[image: output1]

**plotly.graph_objects version :**

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np 

x = np.array([0,1])
y = np.array([1,1])
z = np.array([1,1])

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y,z=z, mode='lines'))
fig.show()
```

output 2:

[image: output2]